# .htaccess replace https://example.com/application to https://app.example.com/application

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
https://example.com/
```

is a WP blog, but due to some past implications, the path:

```
https://example.com/application
```

Must lead to `https://app.example.com/application` to keep some URLs spread around the web from breaking (they're already broken, hence this question).

Whats the best way to make this change?

I have tried this so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://app.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

But unfortunately this isn't doing the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the redirect rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^application(.*)$ https://app.example.com/application$1 [r=301,nc]
```

You can also try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://example.com/application$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.example.com/application/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey @Aborted, I've edited my answer and put another option for you to try.